# node.js module works from command line, not from script

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I've installed jsdom on my windows 8.1 machine.

If I am one directory above my local installation of jsdom, I can call

```
node jsdom
```

and everything works.

However, if, from the same dir / pwd, I call a script (at a different path) with

```
require("jsdom").jsdom;
```

I get errors of the type

```
Error: cannot find module 'jsdom'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node's CLI and `require()` behave slightly differently:

**`node path`** resolves using [`path.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths)

- Behaves like you'd expect your operating system to resolve a path.

**`require(path)`** resolves using [`require.resolve`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_resolve_request_options)

- The *exact* behavior is a little complicated, but basically if the beginning of the string looks like a package name, it will look in `node_modules` for a matching package (i.e. doesn't look like a file system path starting with `./`, `/`, `../`, etc).

---

In your case, you can either install the module with NPM (preferred):

```
npm install jsdom --save

require("jsdom").jsdom;
```

Or include the file directly if you've manually added it to your filesystem:

```
require("./jsdom.js").jsdom;
```